# WAMP: Virtual Host PHP not working

Tags: php, apache, wampserver

My config seems to work, because I can access files under the virtual host, e.g. `http://sailing/test.txt`. But as soon as I try to get on a PHP page, my browsers (Chrome and Firefox) start to download the file (e.g. `http://sailing/phpinfo.php`).

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/wamp/www"
    ServerName  localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "F:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All

        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>

        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/wamp/www/sailing"
    ServerName  sailing
    ServerAlias sailing
    <Directory  "F:/wamp/www/sailing">
        AllowOverride All

        <IfDefine APACHE24>
            Require local
        </IfDefine>

        <IfDefine !APACHE24>
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from all
            Allow from 127.0.0.1 localhost ::1
        </IfDefine>

    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

`localhost`and `localhost/phpmyadmin` are working, too. I'm using WampServer 2.5 (Apache 2.4.9, PHP 5.5.12, MySQL 5.6.17).

A minimal configuration also won't seem to work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/wamp/www"
    ServerName  localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "F:/wamp/www/sailing"
    ServerName  sailing
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: PHP under `localhost` is working.

Comment: @pavlovich If phpMyAdmin works, we can safely assume that PHP is also installed and configured

Comment: Are you sure that the file `F:/wamp/www/sailing/phpinfo.php` does not actually have an invisible `.txt` extension. If you are using `notepad` as an editor it will add the `.txt` extension to make the filename `F:/wamp/www/sailing/phpinfo.php.txt` and if you have not set Explorer (not IE) to `show known extensions` you may have missed that. Use a decent editor `notepad++` is good and free.

Comment: @RiggsFolly thanks for your help. Copying the file to `localhost/phpinfo.php` shows me a working `phpinfo()`, file extensions are always shown and I use `Sublime Text`. :)

Comment: I assume you have defined `sailing` in your `HOSTS` file?

Comment: Yep: `127.0.0.1       sailing`.

Comment: Add a new line to the HOSTS file with `::1 sailing` for IPV6 access

Comment: I did, it's still the same. :(